# How to upload video file using media upload in wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a post type which is used to upload banners in wordpress. Using custom fields for name, image/video and url. The default media upload works fine to upload image/videos, but my problem is I cannot get the video base url to the custom field.

Here is my code that is not able to get the video url. It only gives me video file name.

```
window.send_to_editor = function(html) {

    var imgurlar = html.match(/<img[^>]+src=\"([^\"]+)\"/);
    var imgurl = imgurlar[1];

    //image
    if( imgurl.length ){
        jQuery('#wsp_media').val(imgurl);
        jQuery('#preview-wsp-media').html('<img src="'+imgurl+'" style="max-width:30px; max-height:50px"/><input type="button"  value="Remove" class="button" onclick="removeUspMedia()"/>');
    }
    //video
    else{
        var fileurl = jQuery(html);
            //above "html" carries only video name if I click on "none" button in media library

        //check if fileurl is a video ??
        var fName = jQuery(fileurl).attr('href');

        ext = fName.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        var validVideos = [<?php echo "'" . implode("','", explode(' ', $this->validVideos)) . "'"?>];
        if(jQuery.inArray(ext, validVideos) == -1){
            alert('invalid video file selected');
        }else{
            jQuery('#wsp_media').val(fName);
            jQuery('#preview-wsp-media').html('<img src="<?php bloginfo('url')?>/wp-includes/images/crystal/video.png" style="max-width:30px; max-height:50px"/><input type="button"  value="Remove" class="button" onclick="removeUspMedia()"/>');
        }
    }
    tb_remove();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution myself.

Add a filter in "media_send_to_editor"

```
add_filter('media_send_to_editor', 'media_editor', 1, 3);
```

Append the video url in output html

```
function media_editor($html, $send_id, $attachment ){
    //get the media's guid and append it to the html
    $post = get_post($send_id);
    $html .= '<media>'.$post->guid.'</media>';
    return $html;
}
```

Get the media url like this

```
window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        .......
        .......
        var pathArray = html.match(/<media>(.*)<\/media>/);
        var mediaUrl = pathArray != null && typeof pathArray[1] != 'undefined' ? pathArray[1] : '';
        jQuery('#wsp_media').val(mediaUrl);
        .......
        .......
    }
```